# SSIS PGP encryption

Tags: encryption, ssis, pgp

I have a SSIS package that writes the output to Flat file.
Now I need to **PGP encrypt** the output file and further **decrypt** in other packages. I am curious if anyone knows of how to do this, or better yet a website with helpful hints on how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Is running this programmatically an option?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to do the en/de-cryption within SSIS, the simplest method will probably to explore the command line version of whichever encryption software you are using, and execute it using an `Execute Process` task.

If you haven't yet selected encryption software, obvious choices include [PGP](http://www.pgp.com/products/commandline/servers/index.html) (commercial) and [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) (open source).

The other option would be to write .Net code to carry out en/de-cryption in a `Script Task` - this would require a .dll from PGP or GnuPG. Various generic .Net examples (not specific to SSIS) are available - like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/sharpprivacy.aspx?df=100&forumid=15716&exp=0&select=573797) - but I can't comment on their completeness or quality.

This [SQLServerCentral thread](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic365090-148-1.aspx) may have some useful pointers.

Answer (score 1):

For stable, well-supported and updated PGP-compatible SSIS task check our [BizCrypto](http://www.eldos.com/bizcrypto/ssis-pgp-task.php) product.

Answer (score 1):

Check the third-party commercial CozyRoc SSIS+ library. It includes [OpenPGP Task](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/openpgp-task) and many other useful extensions.